# Easiest way to script drop and create Azure SQL Data Sync group

Tags: sql-server, azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-data-sync

My sync group is out-of-date and currently not syncing correctly to the member database.

First, I would like to script out the existing definition if possible.

If not possible, then I want to create a `PowerShell` script to allow me to drop and re-create the group at any time.

This should be easy, as there is a ton of documentation out there.  I am using this knowledge resource:

https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/azure/sql-database/scripts/sql-database-sync-data-between-sql-databases

but I keep running into this error:

```
Unable to find type [AzureSqlSyncGroupSchemaTableModel]
```

When I run this line:

```
$newTableSchema = [AzureSqlSyncGroupSchemaTableModel]::new()
```

As far as I understand, this is a standard attribute of the namespace `Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Sql.DataSync.Model` so what am I missing?

Comment: Did you get a solution to your question? I'm also experiencing the same issue.